# Disable of viewing previous page in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my project i want to deny going back to the page when i click back button in toolbar.
How its possible in asp.net and c#.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't mess with the user's browser toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this javascript in the html section of an aspx page above the head section.

**This causes every back to return with a forward.**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function disableBackButton()
{
window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
</script>
```

plus have a look at this article
https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml

Comment: how to disable forward button in toolbar

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this by code-behind.Put following code in Page_Load or Page_Init event of the page

```
protected void Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```