# disable browser back button

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

how to disable browser back button that works for all major browsers: IE/FF/ Chrome/Opera/Safari.

thanks!

Comment: If you want to disable the back button from within your website, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I sure hope I *never* find myself on any website you create.

Comment: Its not possbile, but there is some around if you click back, you handle, look this thread and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644778/disable-of-viewing-previous-page-in-asp-net/5644791#5644791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use history.forward(); in your source page** from where you are going to the target page.now if u try to go back to the previous page u can't.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  history.forward();
</script>
```

disabling the browser button is not possible but try this solution if u want to implement in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to disable the browser back button. There are couple of work arounds:

1. Open your website in a window without the toolbar so back button is not visible. But this will not enable any shortcut key (like backspace) for the back button.
2. Another work around is to use AJAX to update your DOM always so that back button is never enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's is technically impossible to disable the back button, but maybe [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911/Disabling-the-Back-Button.htm) will help you out. It shows you some 'tricks' to achieve the same functionality.

But you can also use AJAX and load everything asynchronous (so the user will always be on the same single page)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below script which is working code, put this code on your web page(.aspx).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    noBack();
    window.onload = noBack;
    window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack(); }
    window.onunload = function() { void (0); }

</script>
```

Happy coding !!